# Reading any error in log for last 5 mins only

Tags: shell-script

This is how my log file looks like:

```
2019-03-17 13:49:01.267 MESSAGE Web  
2019-03-17 13:50:04.325 ERROR error msg: ConnectivityException  
2019-03-17 14:15:20.326 ERROR error msg: Error occurred invoking AgentConnector.call() method  
2019-03-17 14:30:30.326 WARNING start: Web  
2019-03-17 14:49:12.327 ERROR exec-10 - null
```

I have to read through this log every 5 mins and catch any error happened during last 5 mins i.e when I read this log at 14:16 pm, I should only get 1 error, which happened at 14:15 but not 13:50 pm error. My script exits at every run.

I read we can do this using "dd" but I m not getting it to write in a script form.

```
dd if="$in_file" iflag=skip_bytes,count_bytes,fullblock bs="$block_size" skip="$start" count="$copy_size"
```

Any other way to get this done.

Comment: i hope we should check past 5 mins log instead of next 5mins...

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set cron job to look for error, perform following:

1. Create script to **tail** lines from the error file to get the latest error.
2. Then pipe the output with "Error".
3. Add the script in cron (*/5 * * * * PATH_TO_SCRIPT)

Comment: I guess you mean */5. How does this only yield errors that happened in the last 5 minutes, though?

Comment: correct @DonHolgo

Comment: No , error can vary time to time

Comment: Any other solution ? Above tail solution doesnot seem to be working . How do we tick what we have read before and what we will read in current run ?Please help with other solutions

Comment: You can add `tail -F` which will tail the current file.